# Error when running cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundle

My configiration is centOS 6.5 postgras93 ruby 1.9.3 ruby on rails 3

I have an error when tring to run

```
cap deploy:cold
```

i have ran the bundle command and know that pg 0.15.1 is installed

i have also ran this command as well

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config
```

here is the error

```
    servers: ["www.loadmax.com", "workers.loadmax.com"]
    [www.loadmax.com] executing command
    [workers.loadmax.com] executing command
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed
to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com]
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extc
onf.rb
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] checking for pg_config... no
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, p
lease try again with
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] checking for libpq-fe.h... no
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] *** extconf.rb failed ***
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, proba
bly lack of
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf
```

when i run gems list i get this:

```
[root@ip-50-63-158-250 cached-copy]# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.2, 3.2.3)
actionpack (4.0.2, 3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activerecord-postgis-adapter (0.6.3, 0.4.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (4.0.2, 3.2.3)
addressable (2.3.4)
arel (3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.14)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4, 3.0.3)
bullet (4.4.0)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.3.4, 1.2.3)
cancan (1.6.10, 1.6.8)
capistrano (2.14.2, 2.13.4)
capybara (2.0.2)
celluloid (0.15.2)
childprocess (0.3.9)
choice (0.1.6)
chronic (0.7.0)
client_side_validations (3.2.5)
coderay (1.0.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2, 1.3.3)
commonjs (0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (0.9.1)
deploy (0.0.3)
devise (2.1.2)
devise-encryptable (0.1.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.4, 1.1.3)
domain_name (0.5.11, 0.5.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (2.0.2, 1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.3.0, 4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
faker (1.1.2)
faraday (0.8.4)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.8.1)
formatador (0.2.4)
gauges-rails (0.2.1)
god (0.13.4, 0.13.1)
google-spreadsheet-ruby (0.3.0)
google_drive (0.3.1)
growl (1.0.3)
guard (2.4.0, 1.8.0)
guard-rspec (3.0.0)
guard-spork (1.5.1, 1.5.0)
haml (4.0.2, 3.1.7)
highline (1.6.18, 1.6.15)
hike (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
httparty (0.11.0, 0.9.0)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
iconv (1.0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
jruby-pageant (1.1.1)
json (1.7.7, 1.7.5)
jwt (0.1.5)
kgio (2.8.0)
launchy (2.3.0)
less (2.3.2, 2.2.2)
less-rails (2.3.3, 2.2.3)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
listen (2.4.0, 1.0.3)
log4r (1.1.10)
lumberjack (1.0.3)
macaddr (1.6.1)
mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
mechanize (2.6.0, 2.5.1)
method_source (0.8.1)
mime (0.1)
mime-types (2.1, 1.23, 1.19)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.3, 1.3.6)
multi_xml (0.5.3, 0.5.1)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-http-digest_auth (1.3, 1.2.1)
net-http-persistent (2.8, 2.7)
net-scp (1.1.0, 1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.1.2, 2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.7, 2.6.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
nexmo (1.2.0)
nokogiri (1.5.9, 1.5.5)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paypal-sdk-core (0.2.7)
paypal-sdk-merchant (1.106.1)
paypal-sdk-rest (0.6.0)
pg (0.15.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pony (1.4.1, 1.4)
pry (0.9.12.1)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.5.0, 1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.3)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.11, 1.0.9)
railties (3.2.3)
raindrops (0.11.0)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12)
redis (3.0.1)
redis-namespace (1.3.0, 1.2.1)
resque (1.21.0)
resque_spec (0.13.0)
rgeo (0.3.20, 0.3.19)
rgeo-activerecord (0.5.0, 0.4.5)
rgeo-geojson (0.2.3)
roo (1.11.2, 1.10.1)
rspec (2.13.0, 2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1, 2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0, 2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1, 2.11.3)
rspec-rails (2.13.1, 2.11.0)
ruby-gmail (0.3.0, 0.2.1)
ruby-growl (4.0)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.6, 1.2.11.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.8, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.32.1)
sendmail (0.0.1)
shared-mime-info (0.1)
shoulda-matchers (2.1.0)
sinatra (1.3.6, 1.3.3)
slop (3.4.4)
spork (0.9.2)
spreadsheet (0.8.5, 0.7.3)
sprockets (2.1.3)
systemu (2.5.2)
therubyracer (0.10.2)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
timers (1.1.0)
todonotes (0.1.0)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6, 2.1.9)
twitter_bootstrap_form_for (1.0.5)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.33)
tzip (0.0.4)
uglifier (2.1.0, 1.3.0)
unf (0.1.1, 0.0.5)
unf_ext (0.0.6, 0.0.5)
unicorn (4.6.2)
uniform_notifier (1.2.0)
uuid (2.3.7)
uuidtools (2.1.4)
vegas (0.1.11)
warden (1.2.1)
watchr (0.7)
webrobots (0.1.1, 0.0.13)
websocket (1.0.7)
whenever (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
will_paginate (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
will_paginate-bootstrap (0.2.2, 0.2.1)
xml-simple (1.1.3)
xpath (1.0.0)
```

Here is the full error

```
  * ←[33mexecuting "cp -RPp /home/deployer/loadmax/shared/cached-copy /home/depl
oyer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840 && (echo 09088e877cce118abff9d67013b3aa2155
6b8c71 > /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840/REVISION)"←[0m
    servers: ["www.loadmax.com", "workers.loadmax.com"]
    [www.loadmax.com] executing command
    [workers.loadmax.com] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 424ms←[0m
  * ←[32m2014-04-06 17:18:41 executing `deploy:finalize_update'←[0m
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * ←[32m2014-04-06 17:18:41 executing `bundle:install'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840 && bundle
install --gemfile /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840/Gemfile --path
/home/deployer/loadmax/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development
test"←[0m
    servers: ["www.loadmax.com", "workers.loadmax.com"]
    [www.loadmax.com] executing command
    [workers.loadmax.com] executing command
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed
to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com]
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extc
onf.rb
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] checking for pg_config... no
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, p
lease try again with
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] checking for libpq-fe.h... no
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] *** extconf.rb failed ***
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, proba
bly lack of
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf
.log file for more
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] details.  You may need configuration options.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com]
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Provided configuration options:
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-opt-dir
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-opt-dir
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-opt-include
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-opt-lib
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-make-prog
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-make-prog
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --srcdir=.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --curdir
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ru
by
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-dir
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg-dir
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-include
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-lib
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg-config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg-config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --with-pg_config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] --without-pg_config
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com]
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com]
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Gem files will remain installed in /home/deployer/l
oadmax/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1 for inspection.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Results logged to /home/deployer/loadmax/shared/bun
dle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] An error occurred while installing pg (0.15.1), and
 Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: www.loadmax.com] Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.15.1'` succeed
s before bundling.
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 91186ms←[0m
*** [←[34mdeploy:update_code←[0m] ←[34mrolling back←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "rm -rf /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840; true"
←[0m
    servers: ["www.loadmax.com", "workers.loadmax.com"]
    [www.loadmax.com] executing command
    [workers.loadmax.com] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 368ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840 && bundle inst
all --gemfile /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140406221840/Gemfile --path /hom
e/deployer/loadmax/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test
'" on www.loadmax.com
```

Comment: Is the package `postgresql-libs` installed on the machine?

Comment: Package postgresql93-libs-9.3.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's trying to do a DB migration as part of deploy:cold.
Can you do a:

cap deploy
cap deploy:migrations